# Get paragraphs of a certain length in Applescript (and then do something with those paras)

Tags: text, applescript

Could I turn a list of songs into two separate lists: one where song titles are three words or less and one where they are four words or more? I want to take one list (as a variable) and run an action on it and then a separate action on the other list.

Here's as far as I got:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
activate
tell the front document
    set my_list to every paragraph whose (count of words) is 2
end tell
end tell
```

I can't seem to get the property of the number of words in each paragraph to work - I'm getting the error message: "TextEdit got an error: Can’t make 2671 into type reference."

---

It might help to explain what I am going to do next.

I'd get paragraphs of that list

```
set MySongs to paragraphs of my_list
-- read artist names (separated by newlines) from the file
```

And then add them to an iTunes playlist:

```
tell application "iTunes"
repeat with AnItem in MySongs -- get all tracks from each artist
    set AnItem to (contents of AnItem)
    if AnItem is not "" then try -- don't bother with empty names
        set MyTracks to (location of file tracks of playlist "Music" whose name is AnItem)
        --can also modify the above from "is" to "contains" or "_begins with_"
        add MyTracks to NewPlaylist
    on error errmess -- oopsie (not found, etc)
        log errmess -- just log it
    end try
end repeat
end tell
```

And then do a similar thing with the second list.

So: is it possible to get just the paragraphs from a text doc that are less than 4 words and make that into a variable to pass on in this fashion?

Thanks

Tardy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think you're trying to accomplish.

```
set mySampleText to "this is
my sample text data, lets see what happens if we
have different
length paragraphs"

set paras to paragraphs of mySampleText
set list1 to {}
set list2 to {}
repeat with apara in paras
    set apara to apara as string
    if (count of words in apara) is less than or equal to 2 then
        set end of list1 to apara
    else
        set end of list2 to apara
    end if
end repeat
```

At the end of this script, you'll have two lists: list1 (the items with 2 words or less) and list2 (the items with 3 or more words).

On a side note, I would recommend against scripting TextEdit. There is really no reason to do so. You can just `read` your text file directly into your script and work with it.

For example...

```
set mySampleText to read file "Macintosh SSD:path:to:file.txt"
```